# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Tags: python, valueerror

```
def load_data(dataset='data.pkl.gz'):
      dataset = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], '../data', dataset)
      f = gzip.open(dataset, 'rb')
      train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f)
      f.close()
```

when I want to call this file (load_data) in another file, I get this error message.

> **in load_data**
>
> train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f)
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: What do you get if you try `print(pickle.load(f))`?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 "Too many values..." implies that `pickle.load(f)` unpacks to *more* than three values

Comment: Oops, you're right.

Comment: nothing appears when I print(pickle.load(f)) @PatrickHaugh so what should i do?

Comment: inside the load_data file I also create def make_numpy_array (data_xy): which will to make train_set, valid_set, test_set

Comment: @V.OVian I'd expect it to return None value at least? make sure you run it before f.close()

Comment: @PatrickHaugh No change, the error remains the same...

Answer (score 0):

your load function returns less values, so try to delete one of the variable at the receiving end..

Comment: I tried deleting, but I found the message [TypeError: load_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given]